# Regexp to Compare partial filenames then moving to another directory perl

Tags: file, perl, filesystems, move

I am working on a script to compare non-running files within a dir to running files from a command. I have to use Regex to strip the front half of the filenames from the dir then regex to strip the filenames out of a command which then records the unmatched names into an array.

The part I cannot figure out is how I can move the filenames from the old dir into a new directory for future deletion.

In order to move the files I will need to enclose them in wildcards, * due to the random numbers in front of the filenames and the extention. 
example filenames before and after:

within dir:

13209811124300209156562070_cake_872_trucks.rts

within command:

{"file 872","cake_872_trucks.rts",running}

in `@events` array:

cake_872_trucks

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy qw(move);
use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util 'max';
my $orig_dir = "/var/user/data/";
my $dest_dir = "/var/user/data/DeleteMe/";
my $dir = "/var/user/data";
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Could not open $dir: $!\n";
my @allfiles = readdir DIR;
close DIR;
my %files;
foreach my $allfiles(@allfiles) {
$allfiles =~ m/^(13{2}638752056463{2}635181_|1[0-9]{22}_|1[0-9]{23}_|1[0-9]{24}_|1[0-9]{25}_)([0-9a-z]{4}_8[0-9a-z]{2}_[0-9a-z]{2}[a-z][0-9a-z]0[0-9]\.rts|[a-z][0-9a-z]{3}_[0-9a-z]{4}_8[0-9a-z]{2}_[0-9a-z]{2}[a-z]{2}0[0-9]\.rts|[a-z]{2}[0-9a-z][0-9]\N[0-9a-z]\N[0-9]\N[0-9]\N[0-9a-z]{4}\N[0-9]\.rts|[a-z]{2}[0-9a-z]{2}\N{2}[0-9a-z]{2}\N{2}[0-9][0-9a-z]{2}\N[0-9]{2}\.rts|S0{2}2_86F_JATD_01ZF\.rts)$/im;

$files{$2} = [$1];
    }
my @stripfiles = keys %files;
my $cmd = "*****";
my @runEvents = `$cmd`;
chomp @runEvents;
foreach my $running(@runEvents) {
$running =~ s/^\{"blah 8[0-9a-z]{2}","(?<field2>CBE1_D{3}1_8EC_J6TG0{2}\.rts|[0-9a-z]{4}_8[0-9a-z]{2}_[0-9a-z]{2}[a-z][0-9a-z]0[0-9]\.rts|[a-z]{2}[0-9a-z]{2}\N{2}[0-9a-z]{2}\N{2}[0-9][0-9a-z]{2}\N[0-9]{2}\.rts)(?:",\{239,20,93,5\},310{2},20{3},run{2}ing\}|",\{239,20,93,5\},310{2},[0-9]{2}0{3},run{2}ing\}|",\{239,20,93,5\},310{2},[0-9]{3}0{4},run{2}ing\}|",\{239,20,93,5\},3[0-9]0{2},[0-9]{2}0{4},run{2}ing\})$/$+{field2}/img;

}
my @events = grep {my $x = $_; not grep {$x =~/\Q$_/i}@runEvents}@stripfiles;
foreach my $name (@events) {
my ($randnum, $fnames) = { $files{$name}};
my $combined = $randnum . $fnames;
print "Move $file from $orig_dir to $dest_dir";
move ("$orig_dir/$files{$name}", $dest_dir)
or warn "Can't move $file: $!";
}
#print scalar(grep $_, @stripfiles), "\n";
#returned 1626
#print scalar(grep $_, @runEvents), "\n";
#returned 102  
#print scalar(grep $_, @allfiles), "\n";
#returned 1906
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that supports (and improves) the description?  While I get _some_ idea from the description, the code makes no sense and altogether I have no idea what you problem is. Apart from the code being unrelated to the description, it is not shown what is in the `@events` (which is undeclared), and your `mv` is given strange (unexplained) arguments.

Comment: Added the left out code.

Comment: (1) when you use `map` on `@events` you get a list, which you then `join` by space; this results in _one_ string.  So when you assign that to `@events`, the array stays with one element, that one string. Is that intended? (2) That `mv` would move the directory `...RunBack` and `$_` into the directory `.. files/`. Is that intended?

Comment: That is not intended.  I want to move each file within the array from one directory to another.

Comment: Alright, thought so.  Will try to look at it tonight. It doesn't help that your regexes are incomplete and that this is clearly not the code that "_attempts to move the full directory_" (it won't compile).  I cleaned up a little. (Btw, such a  regex is an absolute horror.)

Comment: So the files in `@events`  should be moved from `RunBackup` to `RunBackup/files`?

Comment: Yes the files in @events are stripped of the front random number and .extention. I want to then move them from RunBackup to RunBackup/files but I no longer have the random number in the begining of the file name or the .extention.  I was hoping to use a wildcard mv *<@events>* but the wildcard doesn't translate to the mv command.  Maybe I need to use a regex to put the random number and extention back?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest to modify the regex so to capture parts.  See the posted answer.

Comment: Since I am still unsure which files need be moved the answer I posted guesses and has two versions. Hopefully that is enough but please let me know if things aren't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are parsing filenames with regex there is no reason not to be able to capture all parts so that you can later reconstitute needed parts of the filename.

I assume that that overly long (and incomplete) regex does what it is meant to.

I am not sure how the files to move relate to the original files in `@allfiles`, since those are fetched from `/var/user/data` while your moving attempt uses `/home/user/RunBackup`. So code snippets below are more generic.

If what gets moved are precisely the files from `@allfiles` then just keep the file name

```
my %files;

foreach my $oldfile (@allfiles) {
    $oldfile =~ m/...(...).../;    # your regex, but capture the name
    $files{$1} = $oldfile;
}
```

where by `/...(...).../` I mean to indicate that you use your regex, but to which you add parenthesis around the part of the pattern that matches the name itself.

Then you can later retrieve the filename from the "name" of interest (`cake_872_trucks`).

If, however, the filename components may be needed to patch a different (while related) filename then capture and store the individual components

```
my %files;

foreach my $oldfile (@allfiles) {
    $oldfile =~ m/(...)(...)(...)/;  # your regex, just with capture groups
    $files{$2} = [$1, $3];           # add to %files: name => [number, ext]
}
```

The regex only matches (why change names in `@allfiles` with `s///`?), and captures.

The first set of parenthesis captures that long leading factor (number) into `$1`, the second one gets the name (`cake_872_trucks`) into `$2`, and the third one has the extension, in `$3`.

So you end up with a hash with keys that are names of interest, with their values being arrayrefs with all other needed components of the filename.  Please adjust as needed as I don't know what that regex does and may have missed some parts.

Now once you go through `@events` you can rebuild the name

```
use File::Copy qw(move);

foreach my $name (@events) {
    my ($num, $ext) = @{ $files{$name} };
    my $file = $num . $name . $ext;
    say "Move $file from $orig_dir to $dest_dir";
    move("$orig_dir/$file", $dest_dir)  or warn "Can't move $file: $!";
}
```

But if the files to move are indeed from `@allfiles` (as would be the case in this example) then use the first version above to store filenames as values in `%files` and now retrieve them

```
foreach my $name (@events) {
    move ("$orig_dir/$files{$name}", $dest_dir) 
        or warn "Can't move $file: $!";
    }
```

I use the core module [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html), instead of going out to the system for the move command.

You *can* also rebuild the name by going through the directory again, now with names of interest on hand. But that'd be very expensive since you have to try to match every name in `@events` for every file read in the directory (*O(mn)* complexity).

What you asked about can be accomplished with [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) (and note [File::Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html)'s version)

```
my @files = glob "$dir/*${name}*";
```

but you'd have to do this for every `$name` -- a huge and needless waste of resources.

---

If that regex really must spell out specific numbers, here is a way to organize it for easier digestion (and debugging!): break it into reasonable parts, with a separate variable for each.

Ideally each part of alternation would be one variable

```
my $p1 = qr/.../;
my $p2 = qr/.../;
...

my $re_alt = join '|', $p1, $p2, ...;

my $re_other = qr/.../;

$var =~ m/^($re_alt)($re_other)(.*)$/;  # adjust anchors, captures, etc
```

where the [`qr` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) builds a regex pattern.

Adjust those capturing parenthesis, anchors, etc to your actual needs. Breaking it up so that the regex is sensibly split into variables will go a long way for readability, and thus correctness.

Assuming that there is a good reason to seek those specific numbers in filenames, this is also a good way to document any such fixed factors.

Comment: Sorry.  I am new to perl.  I am trying to use my %files;

foreach my $oldfile (@allfiles) {
    $oldfile =~ m/...(...).../;    # your regex, but capture the name
    $files{$1} = $oldfile;
}            But I keep having an error: Use of uninitialized value $1 in hash element.  I can print out $1 or $2 with my modified regex and see either the random number with $1 or the name of the file with $2.  I will post updated code when I can.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @nANa By that I meant to indicate that you use your regex, in which you add parenthesis around the part of the pattern that matches the name itself (`cake_872_trucks`).  Then that gets saved into the `$1` variable which you can use for the hash key, and assign the filename as the value for that key.  Sorry it's not a complete program but i just don't understand a few important details in your problem.

Comment: @nANa  Added a little below that part of the code, like my comment above; does this help?

Comment: I was able to modify my regex and pull out $1 and $2 and export them into a hash but for whatever reason the numbers do not match up.  I have 1906 files in the dir it reads from and $2 will record 1906 entries but the hash ends up with 1626 keys.  Any idea why that would be?

Comment: @nANa If you are referring to `$files{$2} = [$1];` then (1) I don't understand: if your `$2` is captured for all entries how does the hash end up with less? The `$2` _are_ the keys.  (2) I don't see another set of parens in that regex but: if you attempt to assign a value to a key that doesn't exist (`$files{$2} = ..` when `$2` is undefined) you'll get a warning. Since you don't mention that it appears that you get keys for all attempted matches (all `$2` are defined).

Comment: @nANa Note: (1) if your `$1` is indeed the filename then just use `$allfiles` (not a good name for the name of a file, though), like I do in the answer  (2) If you only assign `$1` as  a value you don't need it in an arrayref (`[..]`), but can do `$h{$2} = $1` (or use the filename if that's indeed the same).  I used an arrayref in case there are more factors to save.

Comment: No matter what I try I cannot get the hash to match what the regex finds for the cake_872_trucks.rts files.  If I print them out within the for loop I have the correct number 1906 but the hash ends up with 1626.  The @allfiles array also has 1906.  I am so confused why it will not input all of them in.

Comment: I powered through it and did a test and found that the files it left behind have the same names!  I do not know how to account for that... but that is sure a step in the right direction!  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @nANa Great! :)) That makes sense (if I got it right), as the code find new files with the same `cake` part and enters that key -- it overwrites the previous (same) key.  So all it needs is that that part, `cake_872_trucks`, is the same. If there is anything in general I can say, that is: try to simplify that regex. It's great that you got  that "monster" to work but it's all harder with such a complicating thing!  Perhaps (in the future), try to devise a careful naming scheme for files so you don't end up with such numbers (if you control that)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this:

```
my $path = '/home/user/RunBackup/';
my @files = map {$path."*$_*"} @events;
system(join " ", "mv", @files, "/home/user/RunBackup/files/");
```

If there are lots of files you might need to move them one by one:

```
system(join " ", "mv", $_, "/home/user/RunBackup/files/") for @files;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with moving the files one by one but I get a mv: cannot stat '/home/user/RunBackup/*cake_872_trucks* no such file or directory. I am thinking that somehow the * is not being passed correctly as a wildcard?

Comment: Wildcards work when you pass the command as single string. You may need to escape filenames. But it seems that in your case filenames are ok as is.